# Python traceback.print_exc() returns 'None'

Tags: python, exception, traceback

This function is supposed to catch exceptions in the main execution. If there is an exception it should print out the error with `log.error(traceback.print_exc())` and clean up with `exit_main()`.

```
def main():
    try:
        exec_app()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        log.error('Error: Backup aborted by user.')
        exit_main()
    except Exception:
        log.error('Error: An Exception was thrown.')
        log.error("-" * 60)
        log.error(traceback.print_exc())
        log.error("-" * 60)
        exit_main()
```

Unfortunately `log.error(traceback.print_exc())` does only return `None` if there is an exception. How can I make traceback print the full error report in this case?

PS: I use python 3.4.

Comment: Which type of exception are you expecting to be logged with `traceback.print_exc()`? it would logs all exceptions except `KeyboardInterrupt`

Comment: Yes. It should handle all exceptions that I haven't caught inside `exec_app()`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

From its `__doc__`:

```
Shorthand for 'print_exception(sys.exc_type, sys.exc_value, sys.exc_traceback, limit, file)'
```

That is, it isn't supposed to return anything, its job is to print.  If you want the traceback as a string to be logged, use `traceback.format_exc()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use `traceback.print_exc()` just for debugging. In your case, to log your exception you can simply do the following:

```
try:
    # Your code that might raise exceptions
except SomeSpecificException as e:
    # Do something (log the exception, rollback, etc)
except Exception as e:
    log.error(e)  # or log(e.message) if you want to log only the message and not all the error stack
```